# How to make caption bold in ctable?

Tags: tables, formatting, captions

If I use

```
\ctable[caption = \textbf{something}]{}{}{}
```

the text inside the caption is bold but TABLE 1. is not ... It looks like this:

> TABLE 1: **something**

and i would like

> **TABLE 1: something**

Comment: You can increase your chance for good (and quick) answers if you add a complete but [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to your question.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the `caption` package and set `\captionsetup[table]{font=bf,position=below}` to get bold label and caption text. The `position=below` is necessary to get the right spacing of the caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=bf,position=below}
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}
This is a row of text, so we can see the whitespace around the table

\ctable[
caption = Centered,pos=hbtp!
]{cc}{}{\FL Table's first row & Second column\LL}

This is a row of text, so we can see the whitespace around the table
 \end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for `position=below`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't like to use the `caption` package, for example in case in would interfere with `ctable` somehow (`ctable` is not mentioned in the `caption` documentation), you could redefine the macro which prints the caption and is usually defined by the class. A small example:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\@stdmakecaption}{\@makecaption}
\renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{\bfseries\@stdmakecaption{#1}{#2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the Preamble

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} %% for the figure and Tables Catption%%
\usepackage[textfont=bf]{caption}   %% For the Text of the figures and Tables%%
```