# How we can make term 'Figure' to be bold and rest part of the caption to remain as it is?

Tags: floats, captions

How to make term 'Figure' bold and rest of the caption need not to be bold

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you're using the `caption` package, this can be specified in `\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}` for example. Without seeing any example, it's difficult to provide a clear answer

Comment: This is a similar request to [How to make caption bold in `ctable`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53708/5764)

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question is not clear because you say

> need not to be bold

Anyways, I am answering both.

If you want to have bold label then simply use

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
```

However if you want to have label and cation both bold, use

```
\usepackage[textfont=bf, labelfont =bf]{caption}
```

The above set up will make changes to both figure and table environments. If you want to make that change only in figure environment, use

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
```

Hope it fixes your issue.